# parse push notification in wcf service

Tags: .net, wcf, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm trying to implement parse push notification, in some occasions I need the notifications to be sent from wcf service, but it throws "Client-initiated push isn't enabled" exception.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go into the parse web interface for your app, then to settings, then push notifications, then set the `Client push enabled?` to on.